# Meaning of "It's easy when you're done" in a dialogue?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

there was a conversation on a stack and there were some comments, I could not relate to each other.

> **First person commenting on the text :** Do you have any reference to an easy in-place implementation of the merge step in mergesort? (just curious)

> **text owner:** I haven't checked these, but they popped up when I searched. (some links ....)

> **First person** Okay, so easy is in the eye of the beholder. It's easy when you're done.**

I know that in the eye of beholder means that, being easy looks different to every person, but what does `It's easy when you're done` from the same line? or maybe the whole last comment.

Comment: **When you're done** usually means **when you have done/completed it**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q.

> Meaning of “It's easy when you're done”

---

A. After you have completed a task, (particularly one that seemed difficult at the time). Now looking back the task seems an easy one. (because now you know how to do it).

Answer (score 1):

> It's easy when you're done.

It means that it looks easy when the problem is already solved/code is already written etc but might not looks that easy when the problem was unsolved.